# Login with Facebook, Android Studio

Tags: java, logcat

**java**

I am trying to log in with facebook in my app but it doesn't log in there is an error.... please help me I am new to this?

callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

```
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());

                        

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                    }
                });

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {


        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.

                            Toast.makeText(FacebookAdapter.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        Intent intent= new Intent(this,HomeLayout.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**logcat**

This is how it shows me the error. I have also done everything in Facebook Developer, and I have also connected the application in Firemase

```
2022-08-14 21:34:35.916 28126-28126/com.example.foodapp D/ViewRootImpl[LogIn]: windowFocusChanged hasFocus=true inTouchMode=true
    2022-08-14 21:34:36.023 28126-13800/com.example.foodapp E/com.facebook.GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Invalid OAuth access token signature.}
    2022-08-14 21:34:36.029 28126-13799/com.example.foodapp E/com.facebook.GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Invalid OAuth access token signature.}
    2022-08-14 21:34:36.031 28126-13796/com.example.foodapp E/com.facebook.GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Invalid OAuth access token signature.}
    2022-08-14 21:34:36.182 28126-13800/com.example.foodapp E/com.facebook.GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Invalid OAuth access token signature.}
    2022-08-14 21:34:36.185 28126-13799/com.example.foodapp E/com.facebook.GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Invalid OAuth access token signature.}
    2022-08-14 21:34:36.325 28126-13799/com.example.foodapp E/com.facebook.GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Invalid OAuth access token signature.}
    2022-08-14 21:34:36.434 28126-13796/com.example.foodapp E/com.facebook.GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Invalid OAuth access token signature.}
    2022-08-14 21:34:36.463 28126-13799/com.example.foodapp E/com.facebook.GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Invalid OAuth access token signature.}
    2022-08-14 21:34:36.598 28126-13799/com.example.foodapp E/com.facebook.GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Invalid OAuth access token signature.}
```

Comment: The error is very clear on what it is. Try searching for that specific error and solution for it.